# Access PC in different subnet via VPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing

I want to a PC Access that is in a different subnet, I come from my PC via a VPN into a Raspberry Pi that gives me access to the gateway and NAS server.
The gateway has the IP address 192.168.1.1 and the router has the IP 192.168.0.1, since the router is also connected to the gateway, I have an IP from it (192.168.1.38), but I can't load the routers page.
Is there a way to “Switch the subnet” through VPN?
Or can I “forward the IP in the gateway”?

I drew the network scheme:

[image: Network schema]

Gateway: Askey 3505VW
WiFi-router: Archer_AX20

My Wireguard settings are:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                     
Address = 10.6.0.4/24              
DNS = 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1                
MTU = 1420               

[Peer]
PublicKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX               
PresharedKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                      
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0                   
Endpoint = Domain.XXX.de:51820
```

Comment: So when you are connected to the PC via the VPN, and you enter `http://192.168.1.38` in your browser, what happens?

Comment: You're already on the `192.168.1.x` subnet if the device has been assigned IP `192.168.1.38` - are you using OpenVPN? If so, you need to enable `client-to-client` and possibly add `dhcp-option` for DNS. Please post your VPN configs, anonymizing private info

Comment: @LawrenceC It loads to death sadly, i think the router is only accessable over the other IP

Comment: @Katze_Mau - You can’t format commentary.  Edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Answer (score 0):

The Archer is an off-the-shelf SoHo Wi-Fi router. From the description it appears IP address 192.168.1.38 is applied to its WAN port.

The WAN port is intended to be connected directly to the internet through the ISP:s router. Consequently the access to the management interface through the WAN port is by default disabled for security reasons. Otherwise if the router was connected to the ISP, any person who found out the public IP could gain access to the device management.

It might be possible to enable the management access also through the WAN port. Either just login through the LAN side and look for it, or check the device manual.